# how to pass parameters from jsp to servlet that returns image

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets

my code from jsp page looks like this:

```
<p>
        <img src="PieChartDemo"/>
</p>
```

I'm loading image from servlet called PieChartDemo. Part of code is here:

```
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream(); 
    response.setContentType("image/png"); 

ChartUtilities.writeChartAsPNG(out, chart, width, height);
```

How can I pass parameter from jsp to this servlet so that it returns my image ?

the parameter I want to send is my Locale attribute. if you know some better way, you can suggest.

I tried to add this code to my servlet, but it didnt help, it was still null.

```
Locale locale = request.getLocale();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach a parameter to the URL of the `src` attribute by doing something like the following.

```
<img src="PieChartDemo?locale=<%= request.getLocale().toString() %>"/>
```